jq - Append element after picking
System Information
jq: 1.7
Pick

Following command works correctly as expected:

jq 'pick(.id,.title,.webpage_url,.channel,.duration_string,.upload_date)' *.info.json

{
  "id": "uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "title": "A transformative new way of classifying foods  BBC",
  "webpage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "channel": "BBC",
  "duration_string": "4:19",
  "upload_date": "20210701"
}

Pick and Append
$ Date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
$ jq 'pick(.id,.title,.webpage_url,.channel,.duration_string,.upload_date)' *.info.json \
  | jq --arg Date="$Date" '. += {"date": $Date}'

{
  "id": "uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "title": "A transformative new way of classifying foods  BBC",
  "webpage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "channel": "BBC",
  "duration_string": "4:19",
  "upload_date": "20210701"
}

Issue

Pick and Append produces same output as Pick and is not appending date. Why and how can I correct this?
also tried + instead of +=, both didn't work (but should work as per Reference 2)

Expected Output
{
  "id": "uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "title": "A transformative new way of classifying foods  BBC",
  "webpage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO8Sn0Xch1s",
  "channel": "BBC",
  "duration_string": "4:19",
  "upload_date": "20210701",
  "date": "2024-05-10"
}

Reference

How to add a field to a JSON object with the jq command? - Stack Overflow
Add new element to existing JSON array with jq - Stack Overflow


--arg needs two arguments but Date="$Date" is just one. Drop the =: jq --arg Date "$Date" 'pick(…) + {"date": $Date}' *.info.json

what is the difference between += and +?

+= provides the LHS as context for the RHS. Thus, . += is pointless.

thanks this solves the problem. I can accept your answer.

@pmf I am trying to append this to another json file:  jq --arg Date "$Date" 'pick(.id,.title,.webpage_url,.channel,.duration_string,.upload_date) + {"date": $Date}' Log.json | jq '. + [input]' Youtube.log.json, where Youtube.log.json is empty json array [ ]. But this is not appending the object to the empty array.

jq cannot read from STDIN and a file at the same time (the input from STDIN would silently be disregarded), but you can reference STDIN as another file using - as in … | jq '. + [input]' file.json -. The order of the file arguments matters, as . will fetch the first JSON input (coming from the file), and input the second (coming from STDIN, if the file contained not more than one).

As suggested by @pmf in the comments
$ Date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
$ jq 'pick(.id,.title,.webpage_url,.channel,.duration_string,.upload_date)' *.info.json \
  | jq --arg Date="$Date" '. += {"date": $Date}'


Building upon above suggestion, following is more concise

jq --arg Date "$Date" 'pick(.id,.title,.webpage_url,.channel,.duration_string,.upload_date) + {"date": $Date}' *.info.json

